# How do I throw an exception in my Java code?

Tags: java

I got a method that prints out the animals' names.
I now need an error to be printed out if the id is not one of the given ones.
How does it work?

```
class Methode {
    static final int DEER = 0;
    static final int BIRD = 1;
    static final int COW = 2;
    static final int PIG = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            printAnimal();
    }

    public static void printAnimal (int id) {
        if (id == DEER) {
            System.out.println("Deer");
        }
        else if (id == BIRD) {
            System.out.println("Bird");
        }
        else if (id == COW) {
                System.out.println("COW");
        }
        else if (id == PIG) {
            System.out.println("Pig");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add an else clause: `else { System.out.println("Error"); }` or `else { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }` if you want an exception.

Comment: `printAnimal();` This is going to throw an error. You should pass in an integer. Secondly, what kind of an error? Do you wish to `throw` an Error or Simply print an error. For the latter "You could just print error"

Comment: @papaya besides 'errors' (whatever that is) are not thrown, exceptions are.

Comment: Catch known exceptions and re-throw custom exceptions with meaningful information and messages (this is ideal practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by error you mean an `Exception` (otherwise I don't know why you didn't simply printed an "error" message like you did in your `else if` branches), then you need to create a custom class which extends `Exception` and throw it in a new `else` branch. Here is an example:

**Exception:**

```
public class NoSuchAnimalException extends Exception {
 public NoSuchAnimalException(String message) {
     super(message);
 }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void printAnimal(int id) throws NoSuchAnimalException {
    if (id == DEER) {
        System.out.println("Deer");
    } else if (id == BIRD) {
        System.out.println("Bird");
    } else if (id == COW) {
        System.out.println("COW");
    } else if (id == PIG) {
        System.out.println("Pig");
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchAnimalException("No such animal");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        printAnimal(6);
    } catch (NoSuchAnimalException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The exception will be thrown in the last `else` (the id provided in method call doesn't meet the previous requirements) and will be handled in the `public static void main()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you call your `printAnimal()` method without a parameter. That's no good.

Secondly, there are two kinda of exceptions in Java, checked and unchecked. You need to consider which kind you're working with.

Checked means your function must be declared by:

`methodName() throws SomeException{
...}`

And accordingly a caller MUST catch exceptions.

Unchecked means you can throw the exception without doing this, but other programmers aren't made aware of (and conversely, not forced to handle) any exceptions thrown.

Exceptions should be created, like classes, inheriting the base type of exception appropriate.

Checked exception

```
class someException extends exception{...}
```

Unchecked exception

```
class someException extends RuntimeException{...}
```

For non custom exceptions they are thrown like so:

The checked exception

```
throw new Exception ('message');
```

The unchecked exception

```
throw new RuntimeException ('message');
```

Please read the [Java doc on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).
Exceptions are an important part of OOP

(This was written on a phone, so there might be a few typos etc.)

Comment: I think that `printAnimal()` was just a minor typo.

Comment: @SebastianI. I was referring to the fact that in the example is called without an argument, which will give a compiler error

Comment: Yes I know, but I was saying that maybe the `printAnimal()` from his example is just a typo or maybe he wanted to emphasize that he just calls the method there (followed by the correct arguments in his real code)

Answer (score 0):

Should use enums and switch for this task:

```
public class Methode {

    public enum Animal {
        DEER (0),
        BIRD (1),
        COW (2),
        PIG (3);

        private final int value;
        private static Map valueMap = new HashMap<>();

        Animal(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        static {
            for (Animal enumVal : Animal.values()) {
                valueMap.put(enumVal.value, enumVal);
            }
        }

        public static Animal valueOf(int animalId) {
            return (Animal) valueMap.get(animalId);
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printAnimal(1);
    }

    public static void printAnimal (int id) throws Exception {
        Animal animal = Animal.valueOf(id);

        if(animal == null) {
            throw new Exception("Animal not found"); //better use own exception
        } else {
            switch (animal) {
                case DEER:
                    System.out.println("Deer");
                    break;
                case BIRD:
                    System.out.println("Bird");
                    break;
                case COW:
                    System.out.println("COW");
                    break;
                case PIG:
                    System.out.println("Pig");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(animal.name());
            }
        }
    }

}
```